# CSS with right border - Nested

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nested

I am attempting to nest some divs. Each div is a unit which contains a right div and a left div. The left div can contain more units or single non-child units. Basic tree structure. However, I can't seem to get the css to work for what I'm going for.

I've created a js fiddle for it, listed below. The code is also below. I've also included a picture of what I'm going for. Any help is appreciated. I am open to jquery/javascript solutions.

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/atsFA/

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="inmain">
        <div class="inleft">
            <div class="inthing">
                Thing THing Thing X
            </div>
            <div class="inmain">
                <div class="inleft">
                    <div class="inthing">
                        thing2 thing2 thing2 X
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="inright">
                    R<br/>
                    I<br/>
                    G<br/>
                    H<br/>
                    T<br/>
                    2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inright">
            R<br/>
            I<br/>
            G<br/>
            H<br/>
            T<br/>
            1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main{
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:grey;
    position:relative;
}
.inmain{
    width:100%;
    border:2px solid black;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
.inleft{
    background-color:blue;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    margin-right:20px;
    height:100%;
}
.inright{
    background-color:green;
    position:absolute;
    width:20px;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Image for Reference
[image]

Comment: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/atsFA/2/) Do u want this??

Comment: @user3168736 Sort of. Your percentages leave some gaps that need to be closed. Also, this needs to work for any number of nested divs (there will be a scroll on the main div allowing for x-axis scrolling. y axis scrolling will be on each inmain div.)

Comment: It's easy to do if it is in this order right1 -> right2 . But u use rightn->rightn-1....right1

Comment: I ll modify it for two divs. But u need jquery to do it dynamically for n divs. Or n css classes. is it ok??

Comment: @user3168736 Unfortunately, I have to do it for right1->rightn. I have no guarantees on how many children there are, as these are user-added controls. I'm open to jquery if that's necessary.

Comment: I just posted you an example, I hope it suits your needs. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the below JQuery method with the css worked. The 22px less on the width is to account for a scroll bar, if one is used.

```
function setConstructSizes(element) {
    //Set split group heights
    element.find(".inthing").each(function () {
        var hR = $(this).parent().parent().children(".inright").first().height();
        if (hR > $(this).height()) {
            $(this).height(hR);
        }
    });
    //Set width of all inner lefts
    element.find(".inleft").each(function () {
        var p = $(this).parent();
        var w = p.width();
        $(this).width(w - 22);
    });
    //Set height of all inner rights
    element.find(".inright").each(function () {
        $(this).height($(this).parent().height());
    });
}

.inmain
{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    text-align:left;
}
.inleft
{
    position:relative;
}
.inright
{
    text-align:center;
    border-left:1px solid black;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    width:20px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used nested classes and nth-child or nth-of-type basing on your html structure.
Bear in mind I have used padding-bottom: 22px to take into account of your 2px border.

You can try:

```
#main{
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    position:relative;
}
.inmain{
    width:100%;   
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
.inmain:nth-of-type(2){
    border:2px solid black;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;  
    width:96%;
}
.inmain:nth-child(1) .inleft{
    background:white;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    margin-right:20px;
    height:100%;
    padding-bottom:22px;
}
.inmain:nth-child(2) .inleft{
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    margin-right:20px;
    height:100%; 
    padding-bottom:0;

}
.inmain .inleft .inmain .inright{
    background-color:#00FF00;
    position:absolute;
    width:20px;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;   
    height:100%;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
.inmain .inright{
    background-color:#00FF00;
    position:absolute;
    width:20px;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;   
    height:100%;
    padding-bottom:22px;
}
```

**Check this DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/atsFA/12/

Comment: That's very close to what I need. The heights aren't lined up though. I ended up just using jquery for this. I'll post it below.

Comment: Sure, glad it was helpful for you. :)